# Авторские слова при цитировании

Tags: цитата

«Ростуризм будет отслеживать информацию о таких продажах (путевок в Турцию. — «Новая») и принимать меры, чтобы этих продаж не было», — в случае нарушения глава Ростуризма Олег Сафонов пригрозил туроператорам санкциями.

Возможно ли такое оформление цитаты?

Comment: После Турции точка точно лишняя.

Answer (score 1):

Такое оформление цитаты некорректно. Т. к. после тире с запятой должны следовать слова автора, указывающие на то, кому принадлежит цитата, или поясняющие ее. В Вашем случае это два разных предложения, в которых нарушена синтаксическая связь.

Возможно такое оформление: «Ростуризм будет отслеживать информацию о таких продажах (путевок в Турцию. — «Новая») и принимать меры, чтобы этих продаж не было», — ***пригрозил туроператорам санкциями, глава Ростуризма Олег Сафонов.***

Если оставить фразу "в случае", получится, что глава Ростуризма пригрозил в случае нарушения, что, согласитесь, нелогично.

Comment: Мне лично нелогичным кажется применение санкций как раз в случае, если нарушения не было. ))) Возможно, что современная политическая ситуация у кого-то вызвала превратное понимание слова "санкции", но не до такой же степени, чтобы накладывать их на тех, кто не нарушает.

Answer (score 0):

Де-юре можно, с удалением точки после "Турция", естественно, смысл мне лично понятен, двусмысленности не вызывает. Единственное, что внутренние кавычки ("Новая") рекомендуется сделать другого рисунка: если внешние - "лапочки", то внутренние "елочки", и наоборот. Это не императивное правило, тем более тут еще и скобки как дополнительный уровень вложенности, но все-таки:

«Ростуризм будет отслеживать информацию о таких продажах (путевок в Турцию — "Новая") и принимать меры, чтобы этих продаж не было», — в случае нарушения глава Ростуризма Олег Сафонов пригрозил туроператорам санкциями.

Что же касается замечания Сержа, то да, некоторое косноязычие имеет место. Не более чем косноязычие. Неприятно, но не смертельно. Предлагаемая же Сержем правка - это еще хуже. )) Откуда там запятая и каков вообще смысл такого преобразования, удаляющего значимое "в случае", непонятно. По Сержу получается что он пригрозил санкциями на случай *ненарушения*?!

Если уж менять фразу, то просто перенести "в случае" в конец и расшифровать "нарушение":

***«Ростуризм будет отслеживать информацию о таких продажах (путевок в Турцию — "Новая") и принимать меры, чтобы этих продаж не было», — глава Ростуризма Олег Сафонов пригрозил туроператорам санкциями в случае нарушения [распоряжения/указания/директивы...].***